# PHP cURL call to API not working, but same API call in Postman works fine

Tags: php, curl

Have a pair of API endpoints that are working in Postman but only 1 is working in my PHP code. The first api gets a bearer token via POST call which is then used to get data via a GET call. Both calls are on the same Salesforce server, just with different endpoints. The POST call is working fine, I get the token, but the 2nd GET call returns a cURL error 52 Empty reply from server. I've logged the URL and Token being used and put them into Postman, it works perfectly. Is there something missing on my cURL GET request that I'm missing? (note: I've commented out the actual API info in the code)

```
//Setup POST cURL call to get Bearer Token (this call works)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//Returns contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// If we get a valid token, call 2nd api to get rental data
if (core_utility::isJson($result)) {
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    $token = $json["access_token"];
    $url = "https://**dataAPIendpoint**/query/?q=SELECT+**dataAPIquery";
    COREManager::Log("URL: " . $url);
    COREManager::Log("Token: " . $token);

    // set-up GET cURL call using Bearer Token from POST call (this call Fails)
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //execute post
    $info = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($info === false) {
        COREManager::Log("cURL error: " . curl_error($ch) . ", cURL error#: " . curl_errno($ch));
        // This returns: cURL error: Empty reply from server, cURL error#: 52
    }
```

As I mentioned, I pull the URL and Token being used in the 2nd call and place it in Postman, using GET and setting the Bearer Token in the Authorization section. It works perfectly, so the variables being used are valid.

Comment: is it likely that there are cookies involved???

Comment: `$url = "https://**dataAPIendpoint**/query/?q=SELECT+**dataAPIquery";` - is the value of that `q` parameter here properly URL-encoded ...?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius no, already double checked that part